# Steps to run spring mvc basic sample application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

So I open up intelliJ ultimate and opened up this application using the pom.xml :

```
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/
```

The application built just fine, and I ran it with tomcat 6 (which I setup).

I just got a default tomcat welcome screen.

What am I missing here?

Clicking run showed:

```
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2.app/Contents/Resources/Java:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Resources:.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 488 ms
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:13 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:13 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:13 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/17  config=null
Jun 23, 2010 8:28:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 796 ms
Connected to server
```

Comment: There is no log that your application is deployed. Check your Intellij configuration and see if it is deploying properly or not

Comment: Inserting my 5 cents: I'd rather go with Glassfish, when I just started developing web applications I found it much much more newbie-friendly than tomcat.

Comment: Teja, do you have a screenshot to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Run/Debug Configurations and check in the settings there that you have created for Tomcat Server that you have selected an artifact to deploy.

If you have artifacts set up then they will be show in the window.

If you don't have artifacts set up then you will need to do this in the Project Structure window. (File -> Project Structure)

[image]